# Round up prices in woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woo-commerce site, in which there are lots of products with 95 / 99 cents in the price (like 3.99).
I need to round up all of the 95 and 99 cents (like 3.99 => 4.00).

Is there a way to bulk update it all in once with sql function?

tnx ahead

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET col=CEIL(col)
```

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Ya you are probably right, although it sounds like the only instances are .95 and .99 ... but CEIL is probably the better route. I edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: can u please post me the full function?

Comment: and it needs to effect only .99 and .95 prices

Comment: @user3237472 that's pretty much the whole function... replace 'table' with the name of your table and 'col' with the name of your column and run it on your database

Comment: If you want to change specific prices: `UPDATE table SET col=CEIL(col) where col-CEIL(col)<.1`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by setting the number of decimals to **0** at **WooCommerce > Settings > General > Number of decimals**